# Axios CERT_HAS_EXPIRED error when connecting to an API, but only from 1 server

Tags: node.js, ssl, axios, certificate

I've got a node 7.7.4 app that connects to an API on another server. It's a POST to get an auth token, using Axios.

Today I started getting an error saying `certificate has expired`, and in the logs I found the following error when logging the axios response.

```
{ Error: certificate has expired
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1094:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:616:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:446:38)
  code: 'CERT_HAS_EXPIRED',
...
```

The only answers I've found online seem to point to the cert error on the API site, but I checked the API server and things seem good. I ran a local instance of the app as well and don't get the error, I was also able to connect with Talend - no errors.

Node is running on an Ubuntu server behind Nginx - it seems like the cert error must originate on the Node server, but I've got no idea how to renew/refresh it - the SSL cert for the actual website is fine.

I've also checked the time settings, rebooted the server, run update/upgrade, with no luck.

I tested NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZE=0 to see if it works (it does), but that's certainly not something I want to turn on in production for more than a quick test.

Any idea what cert is expired and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because the Sectigo Root certificate happened to expire on the server I was connecting to. Browsers are better at dealing with an expired cert in the chain,. Axios/OpenSSL are pickier. I used this page as a guide to getting it sorted out.

[Fixing the Breakage from the AddTrust External CA Root Expiration](https://www.agwa.name/blog/post/fixing_the_addtrust_root_expiration)